# How to set the background of a TableViewCell with a static image?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitableview

I would like to programmatically set an image to the background of each cell in a TableViewCell. Any idea on how to do that ?

Thx in advance,

Stephane

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should implement a tableView delegate method in order to do this because is Apple recomendation.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
}
```

> A table view sends this message to its delegate just before it uses
>   cell to draw a row, thereby permitting the delegate to customize the
>   cell object before it is displayed. This method gives the delegate a
>   chance to override state-based properties set earlier by the table
>   view, such as selection and background color. After the delegate
>   returns, the table view sets only the alpha and frame properties, and
>   then only when animating rows as they slide in or out.

Answer (score 1):

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a UIView with image as background with your tablecell's dimensions and add it to your cell, then you can add rest of the controls and elements on your UIView.